# selecting decimal .00 from oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I cannot select the number in the database as decimal .00 in the database.

I tried to use this query

```
SELECT to_char(lnamt, '99.00')
FROM ln01mast
```

But the output was showing ######.

Comment: What is your expected output and what do you get? Can you offer more details?

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
select to_char(12345678,'999999999999.99') from dual;
```

Refer [Format models](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm) for more understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Your number is too big to fit in the format. Simply use more nines:

```
SELECT to_char(lnamt, '99999999999999.00')
FROM ln01mast
```

Answer (score 1):

And this too:

```
SELECT to_char(123,'FM99999999.00') FROM dual;
```

(will remove trailing spaces).